# Error while compiling MapWinGIS component in Delphi 10.3

Tags: delphi-10.3-rio

I intend to use the MapWinGis component in Delphi 10.3
There are a number of errors when compiling this component
Has anyone used this component to guide me?

Comment: How do you expect to get help without even giving some details such as error message? MadWinGis is C++ code, not Delphi. So what are you using as component?

Comment: it's true
But there is also a unit for Delphi in this collection

Comment: And which error do you get? Show a [minimal, complete, verifiable and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: In this unit, functions are defined as follows. ......>>>>
function TShapefile.SelectShapes(const BoundBox: IExtents; Tolerance: Double; 
                                 SelectMode: SelectMode; var result: OleVariant): WordBool;
begin
  Result := DefaultInterface.SelectShapes(BoundBox, Tolerance, SelectMode, result);
end;
And the error that occurs ....>>> identifiere redeclared: 'result'

Comment: 1) You should [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69989323/edit) instead of adding a comment 2) There is an argument named "result" which is wrong. Change the name of that argument to something like "AResult".

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. As fpiette told you, you should change 'result' to 'AResult' in all functions producing this error.

```
function TShapefile.SelectShapes(const BoundBox: IExtents; Tolerance: Double; SelectMode: SelectMode; var AResult: OleVariant): WordBool; 
begin 
  Result := DefaultInterface.SelectShapes(BoundBox, Tolerance, SelectMode,  AResult); 
end
```

You must also change it in the interface section of MapWinGIS_TLB.pas.
Unfortunately that's not all. Compilation and linking is now possible but I got errors to register the classes TImage, TShape, TPoint, TTable, TLabel, TChart, TGrid, TField because Delphi already uses these names for classes.
So, you must rename these classes (TImage to TMWImage, etc.) in MapWinGIS_TLB.pas.
Afterwards registration of these classes is working and the component TMap should be shown in the ActiveX tab or the tab you defined.